# Space with 'Name Value List' in Sitecore

Tags: glass-mapper

We are using **Glass Mapper** to map the values from Sitecore.
`System.Collection.Specialized.NameValueCollection` is used in **Glass Mapper** class to map `Name Value List` from Sitecore.

This example data is correctly working

> column1css:test1
>   column2css:test2

But the below example is mapping only the first item

> column1css:test1 test3
>   column2css:test2 test4

The second item is not mapping. Please mind the space between the values.

Comment: Is the data getting saved in the field properly (if you show raw values, does it store the data correctly)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what do you use for **Key** and what for **Value**. 
If your case is:
[image]

It should work (be mapped) correctly:

```
public interface INameValueList : ISitecoreItem
{
    [SitecoreField("Values")]
    NameValueCollection Values { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Just check your solution, it is not GlassMapper bug. **Value** can be any string. Whitespaces are not allowed for **Key** only (if you try for example to set **Key** value to "test1 test3" if will be replaced with "test1_test3" automatically on item save).

Answer (score -1):

We ran into that issue as well.  We were able to resolve it by following this blog post.

https://trnktms.com/2016/10/15/sitecore-name-value-list-field-with-special-characters/

One thing to note is that you need to provide the assembly and class when you add the item to the core DB.

[image]